# Display the value depends on refrence number using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

{
"message":{
"Data":"account/product",
"Refno":"654"
}
}

I need output like if data field is as account then Refno will be 64
If my data field is product the Refno will be empty string
I tried this logic:
message.{
"Data":"account",
"Refno":($.Data='account')?$.Refno:""
}
But this logic is not working
Please anyone help me out

Comment: Your solution seems to be working. Account: https://try.jsonata.org/TYObdNW0X, Product: https://try.jsonata.org/UA10IcJNN

Comment: If it is not present in json but I need a data in jaonata how